# Crystal report 2008: How to extract "Report Custom Function" content from the rpt file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, api, crystal-reports

I'm trying to improve upon a utility that basically scan through all our reports and build a (meta?) report on all database, tables, report formula text, etc.  The utility did an excellent job by using VS, via the crystal .net API, and generated the info nicely.

One thing we couldn't figure out was to be able to extract the custom function content from the report.

The closest match I found was a method under: CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.CustomFunctionControllerClass

The catch, however, is that the reports (apparently) has to be within the crystal enterprise repository.

As I'm sure the "Report custom function" is embedded in the report itself and not the repository, does anyone know how to get at this piece of data in the rpt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CustomFunctions
```

or

```
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.CustomFunctionController.GetCustomFunctions
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Craig, but my understanding is that the ReportAppServer requires the Crystal Enterprise.  Is there any way to go around it?